# file_put_contents(cache/2016_02_13_10_00_00.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 74

Tags: php

I was reading a little about this error but i can't get it fix. 
I was searching a way to remove background of an image and i got it but I can see the "timer or countdown".
Here's the php's code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris '); 
include 'GIFEncoder.class.php';


$time = str_replace("/", " ", $_GET["dt"]);



$future_date = new DateTime(date('r',strtotime($time)));
$time_now = time();
$now = new DateTime(date('r', $time_now));

$f = "%a:%H:%I:%S";
$t = "second";

$frames = array();
$delays = array();

$cache_file = "cache/".preg_replace("/[^a-z,A-Z,0-9,_]/", "_", $time).".gif";

$img = imagecreatefrompng('background/1.png'); // bg
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $black);
imagepng($img, $doo);
imagedestroy($img);

$shit = imagecreatefrompng('background/1.png'); // change background 
$delay = 100;
$font = array(
    'size'=>65, // font size
    'angle'=>0,
    'x-offset'=>30, // offset on x asis
    'y-offset'=>80, // offset on y asis
    'file'=>'fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf', // change font (example: handsean.ttf)
    'color'=>imagecolorallocate($shit, 255, 255, 255),
);

for($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++){
    $interval = date_diff($future_date, $now);
    if($future_date < $now){

        $image = imagecreatefrompng($doo); // change background 
        $text = $interval->format('00:00:00:00');
        imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset'] , $font['y-offset'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
        ob_start();
        imagegif($image);
        $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
        $delays[]=$delay;
        $loops = 1;
        ob_end_clean();
        break;
    } else {

        $image = imagecreatefrompng('background/1.png'); // change background 
        $text = $interval->format($f);

        if(preg_match('/^[0-9]\:/', $text)){
            $text = '0'.$text;
        }
        imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset'] , $font['y-offset'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
        ob_start();
        imagegif($image);
        $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
        $delays[]=$delay;
        $loops = 0;
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    $now->modify('+1 '.$t);
}

$gif = new AnimatedGif($frames,$delays,$loops);
    file_put_contents($cache_file, $gif->getAnimation());

header( 'Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime($time)) ); //expire this image
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
$gif->display();
```

LOG ERROR:

```
    [11-Feb-2016 20:37:35 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(cache/2016_02_13_10_00_00.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php on line 74
[11-Feb-2016 20:37:35 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php:26) in /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php on line 76
[11-Feb-2016 20:37:35 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php:26) in /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php on line 77
[11-Feb-2016 20:37:35 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php:26) in /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php on line 78
[11-Feb-2016 20:37:35 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php:26) in /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php on line 79
[11-Feb-2016 20:37:35 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php:26) in /home/iedgmnuq/public_html/./count/index.php on line 80
```

I need your help and tips,
*Greetings!*

**PS: I dont speak english but I tried :}**

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: there is not file or directory. In this case, there is not directory 'cache', I think. Maybe if you try with the absolute path you can have success. With relative path, directory is intended as in same directory of **executing script**

Comment: It looks like you have a path issue, so the file_put_contents can not write to the server. Either you need to adjust the path to be a full path, rather than relative. Or, perhaps the directory is not writable (use chmod).

Comment: This is what happens when you copy/paste bits of code together without understanding what they do.